# What conditions can cause a PCB fuse to fail and act as a resistor?

Tags: resistors, transformer, passive-networks, fuses, transceiver

Context: Tx circuit that shoots 24V pulses into a transformer to get 240V out of it. The purpose is to drive a piezoelectric transducer.

The circuit itself has a fuse protecting it at the entrance (see picture linked for P/N here: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/96PEx.jpg)).

The problem is for some boards, it seems that the fuse has failed and now acts as a resistor (around 30kOhms) which causes decay in signal sent to the transceiver (blue is after the fuse and purple is entry) (see [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AUb2c.jpg)). This is not that weird as I know some fuses can become a resistor (even though I'm not aware of the conditions for it to happen, hence the title).
The voltage goes back to 24V in a linear fashion after the signal is done being pushed-pulled(see [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tdJ3T.png)).

Anyone with a bit more experience might be able to answer the question, thanks a lot in advance :)

PS: Sorry for the less than exhaustive context, company policy imposes that.

[image: Voltage rises after push-pull]
[image: Signal decays because of fuse resistance]
[image: Fuse P/N]

Comment: I assume purple is 10V/div and this is a short cct test, the 2nd after some aging so T constant is much shorter.

Comment: Have you considered a sine current source or a flyback cct instead?

Answer (score 2):

Pulses with low duty factor will erode filament faster than the temperature rise thus non-fusing resistance and more inductive in nH so dI/dt also causes fatigue and reduction in wire diameter with elevates temps below melting point.

You need a better solution like active fusing with 50mV to 100mV current sensing or as Pd permits.

Comment: Wonder if a "crowbar" circuit, detecting excessive voltage across the fuse, would help it open more suddenly and reliably.

Comment: To give some more context, the 24V is push-pulled into the transformer, therefore the voltage after the source is pretty much constant (to some extent, could be considered as noise). How would that explain the change in resistance of the fuse? 30kOhms is not a little resistance in that sense.

Comment: Erosion of fuse rating at weakest link in its path from high pulses exceeding rating but average below 3A causing separation when hot and reconnection on cooling to a whisker connection of high R.  What surge current results do you have of new and old fuses? Fuse resistance is a PTC but in this case after failure NTC from open to high R Due to structure.

Comment: @rdtsc crowbar is possible but not resettable, push-pull must have deadtime and if excessive will pulse with higher-V across Fuse or the highest resistance until clamped or  until deadtime is over. The fast risetime might be going into small inductance before the piezo capacitance, so resonance is expected during deadtime, unless a damping solution was used. Need help?